# import React components with namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

My react component is structured like this.

```
/build
    ..............................
/lib
    /inner
        /InnerComponent.js
        /index.js
    /OuterComponent1.js
    /OuterComponent2.js
    /index.js
.................................
package.json
.................................
```

My `package.json` looks like below

```
 {
      "name": "my-comp",
      .......................
      "main": "build/index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "babel lib -d build",
        "build:watch": "babel lib -w -d build",
        "lint": "eslint lib/**; exit 0",
        "lint:watch": "esw -w lib/**",
        "prepublish": "npm run build"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
          .......................
      },
      "dependencies": {
          .......................
      },
      "directories": {
        "lib": "lib"
      },
      "repository": {
          .......................
      }
    }
```

`OuterComponent1` and `OuterComponent2` can be imported from `lib/index.js` as `import {OuterComponent1,OuterComponent2} from "my-comp"`. I need to import everything in `lib/inner` as `import {InnerComponent} from "my-comp/inner"` (I want to add namespace for the components in `lib/inner` folder). How can i do this after publishing in npm?

Answer (score 0):

You can create named exports from `inner/index.js` like this:

```
export { InnerComponent } from './InnerComponent';
```

Which would then allow an import using:

```
import { InnerComponent } from 'my-comp/inner';
```

Comment: Hi Steve `my-comp` is supposed to be published in npm and installed into some other projects. on giving the above import statement it gives me this error
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'my-comp/inner' in 'H:\workspace\vscode\sample-project\src\components\home\sub'`

Comment: Is the module folder within `node_modules` as `my-comp`? It looks like it is trying to find the module relative to the folder that contains the file with the import import statement

Comment: ya, once installed `my-comp` will come inside node modules of my project

Comment: Ok. Once installed as an npm module I think the import will work. If you're manually adding it to your test project you could just drop the folder into node_modules, or alternatively use a Webpack resolve alias to find the folder properly